# what does +=, -=, *= and /= stand for in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

what does

> +=, -=, *= and /=

stand for in Python? and how do you use it for **while** loop?

Comment: They are shorthand operators.

Comment: I think [you need a programming book](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/) to get you further along than you are now.

Answer (score 5):

They are performing the operation and then assigning it into the variable:

`a += b` is the same as: `a = a + b`

`a -= b` is the same as: `a = a - b`

`a *= b` is the same as: `a = a * b`

`a /= b` is the same as: `a = a / b`

You can use them in a `while` loop in the same way you would use the extended forms:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print i
    i += 1   # The same of i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 5):

These (`+=`, `-=`, `*=` and `/=`) are called [augmented arithmetic assignments](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). They correspond to the following methods:

```
object.__iadd__(self, other)
object.__isub__(self, other)
object.__imul__(self, other)
object.__idiv__(self, other)
```

the `i` semantically means "in-place", which means that they modify the object (or reference in the case of numerics) without having to additionally assign them:

```
while condition:
    foo += bar
```

is equivalent to:

```
while condition:
    foo = foo + bar
```

Comment: `foo += bar` is equivalent to `foo = foo + bar` only, if no other references to `foo` exist! For example, if initially, `foo2 = foo`, then `bar` is added to `foo2` when using `foo += bar` (assuming `foo` is an object that allows inplace addition), but not when using `foo = foo + bar`

Comment: The above comment applies only to mutable objects which support in-place addition - Lists and Dictionary Values and potentially user-defined Classes.

Answer (score 2):

These are Operator assignment shorthands:

```
Operator symbol       Name of the operator    Example     Equivalent construct 

          +=           Addition assignment        x += 4;     x = x + 4;
          -=           Subtraction assignment     x -= 4;     x = x - 4;
          *=           Multiplication assignment  x *= 4;     x = x * 4;
          /=           Division assignment        x /= 4;     x = x / 4;
          %=           Remainder assignment       x %= 4;     x = x % 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not only python , that is in most of programming languages

x=1;
x+=1;
x will be 2

x=1;
x-=1;
x will be 0

x=3;
x*=2;
x will be 6

x=6;
x/=2;
x will be 3

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is how teachers "back in the day" would handle this:

```
i = 2
while i != 1:
   print "I will first do basic research."
   i += 1
   i *= 1
   i /= 1
   i -= 1
```